# How to use Excel to produce Timesheet from MS Outlook calendar?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, vba, power-query

This question is mainly to share my idea.

On daily bases I have problem to fill in my timesheet. I work different hours every day and at the end of the month I have to submit Excel timesheet that shows if  my overtime is balanced with "under time" and how many hours should I finally count.
I don't have time to open special tools or web pages and enter this time every day.
So I came up with idea to fill up timesheet on daily bases in outlook and export it to Excel .
Whole concept works fine for me for some time now so I wanted to share with you this idea.

At the beginning I was in fact exporting Outlook Calendat to csv, importing to Excel and so on... But as coder I don't like to repeat the same work ao I decided to automate this. Especially when Excel VBA can directly read from Outlook
I can't upload ready Excel with VBA code anywhere so all I use will be described in answare to this "question".
Unfortunately tools like Fieldglass don't have import and excel can't be directly used but it is helpful anyway.

So.. let's start...

Answer (score 1):

Idea is to use Outlook calendar as a tool for entering work hours.
Why Outlook? Because I have it opened all the time and it can remind me to adjust time for this or previous day.
You don't need to open any other tool.
You can enter hours manually or use copy - paste or drag - drop. Change start and end time with a mouse.
First we need separate calendar so appointments we will use for entering working hours.

1. Let's create calendar "Work Timesheet" (you can name it differently but adjust VBA accordingly). You can as well share it with manager if he wants to know how long you work on daily bases.
2. Create appointment with subject "WORK" that starts end ends in our "default" working hours.
   It can have reminder so Outlook will remind you that we should adjust time if we need.
   IT should be recurrent. Weekly, every day of the week we work. (it is template, if we need we can add later work in a weekend for example). It is up to you when recurrence ends. Better don't exaggerate as VBA will have to check all appointments to find this from just this month. In future you can delete this calendar and create new one with the same rules. If you have lunch brake every day you can create 2 appointments WORK every day.
3. Recurrent meeting is easy to add but not very useful. Better would be to have single meetings. To achieve this we have to export calendar to csv While exporting click "Map Custom Fields" and select Subject, Start Date, Start Time , End Time , reminder on/off , reminder date and time. Write to file CSV file and import back to Outlook Work Timesheet calendar. Then delete recurrent meeting(s).
4. We enter work hours simply adjusting appointment "WORK". We can have more then one during a day if needed. You can use mouse or edit appointment
5. If we don't work but this is normal working day change subject to "FREE"
6. IF this is free day but you work make appointment with subject "WORK OVER"
   6a. You can change time scale of calendar in View/Current View/ View Settings/Other Settings but you will propably need to change Font as well to fit calendars in the screen. Unfortunately it impacts all calendars. In view / Time scale you can switch to 15min just to adjust day and then switch back to 30 min.
7. Now we need Excel with some VBA and PowerQuery to calculate. I can't upload ready Excel so below I enter VBA code and Power Query M script.
8. Create Excel with 2 sheets: Timesheet and Calc.
9. In "Timesheet" sheet create table (ListObject) "Timesheet" With just 3 columns: Subject, StartDateTime, EndDateTime.
10. Click on "Timesheet" table go to Data / Get data /from Table/Range
11. In Power Query click Advanced Editor and paste M script from below.
12. In close&Load click arrow down and select Close & Load to.
13. Select Table, Existing Sheet and select cell A3 in Calc sheet. (leave some space for button)
14. Calc table should have some grand totals in important columns and be named "Timesheet_calc" in Table Design
    15 Insert somewhere on Calc sheet a button that will trigger macro (VBA below)
    That is more or less everything.
    Of course my codes can be improved. I see many possibilities but I don't have much time to make all possible "nice" changes.
    My VBA in addition:

- allows to choose is this calculation for present month or previous month
- adds new sheet for month and copies values and formats to this sheet from Timesheet and Calc making kind of archive or history
  Appointments:
  WORK is treated as work so is calculates daily work time overtime and undertime.
  FREE is not treated as work but it is work day so undertime is calculated
  WORK OVERTIME is treated as work but standard time is 0 so overtime is calculate (in ex. work in free day)
  Don't mix types in one day. There is no need for that
  FREE can be just 1 hour or 30 min. This time is anyway treated as 0.
  [This is link to Excel file (with VBA and PowerQuery)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jnefza1sNatO2xT1sbYj6iy4eH5iFw3K/view?usp=sharing)

VBA:

```
   Sub Timesheet_import()
        Dim olApp As Object
        Dim olNS As Object
        Dim olFolder As Object
        Dim olApt As Object
        Dim NextRow As Long
        Dim FromDate As Date
        Dim ToDate As Date
        Dim sDate As Date
        sMonth = MsgBox("Shell I use preasent month? " & vbCr & "Yes: This month" & vbCr & "No: Previous month", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
        If sMonth = 6 Then sDate = Now()
        If sMonth = 7 Then sDate = DateAdd("m", -1, Now())
        FromDate = DateSerial(Year(sDate), Month(sDate), 1)
        ToDate = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(sDate, 0)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        If Err.Number > 0 Then Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        NextRow = 2
        Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(9)
        For Each CalendarFolder In olFolder.Folders
        If CalendarFolder.Name = "Work Timesheet" Then GoTo endLoop
        Next
        endLoop:
        Set olFolder = CalendarFolder
        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Timesheet").ListObjects("Timesheet") Set newRow = .ListRows.Add()
        .DataBodyRange.Delete
        For Each olApt In olFolder.Items
        If (olApt.Start >= FromDate And olApt.Start <= ToDate) Then
        Set newRow = .ListRows.Add()
        With newRow
        .Range(1) = olApt.Subject
        .Range(2) = CDate(olApt.Start)
        .Range(3) = CDate(olApt.End)
        End With
        End If
        Next olApt
        End With
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Calc").ListObjects("Timesheet_calc").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit
        Set olApt = Nothing
        Set olFolder = Nothing
        Set olNS = Nothing
        Set olApp = Nothing
        Dim NameNew As String
        NameNew = Year(sDate) & "-" & Month(sDate)
        If WorksheetExists(NameNew) Then
        Sheets(NameNew).Delete
        End If
        lastsheet = Sheets.Count
        Set NewSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(lastsheet))
        NewSheet.Name = NameNew
        Range("Timesheet_calc[#All]").Copy
        NewSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        NewSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        NewSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Range("Timesheet[#All]").Copy
        NewSheet.Range("K1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        NewSheet.Range("K1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        NewSheet.Range("K1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        End Sub
        Function WorksheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
            Dim sht As Worksheet
            If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
            On Error Resume Next
            Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            WorksheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
        End Function
```

M script for Power Query

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Timesheet"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Start Date", each Date.From([StartDateTime])),
     #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom" , "Start Time", each Time.From([StartDateTime])),
     #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2" , "End Time", each Time.From([EndDateTime])),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom3",{{"Start Time", type time}, {"End Time", type time}, {"Start Date", type date}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"StartDateTime", "EndDateTime"}),
    mSort = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"Start Date", Order.Ascending}, {"Start Time", Order.Ascending}}),
    WorkTime = Table.AddColumn(mSort, "WorkTime", each if [Subject] = "WORK" or [Subject]="WORK OVER" then [End Time]-[Start Time] else "00:00:00"),
    WorkTimeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(WorkTime,{{"WorkTime", type duration}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(WorkTimeType, {"Start Date"}, {{"Subject", each List.Min([Subject]), type text}, {"Start Time", each List.Min([Start Time]), type nullable time}, {"End Time", each List.Max([End Time]), type nullable time}, {"Work Time", each List.Sum([WorkTime]), type nullable duration}}),
    StandardTime = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Standard time", each if [Subject]="WORK" or [Subject]="FREE" then "08:00:00" else "00:00:00"),
    StandardTimeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(StandardTime,{{"Standard time", type duration}}),
    OverTime = Table.AddColumn(StandardTimeType, "OverTime", each if[Work Time]-[Standard time]>=Duration.From("00:00:00")  then [Work Time]-[Standard time] else "00:00:00"),
    OverTimeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(OverTime,{{"OverTime", type duration}}),
    UnderTime = Table.AddColumn(OverTimeType, "UnderTime", each if[Work Time]-[Standard time]<Duration.From("00:00:00")  then -[Work Time]+[Standard time] else "00:00:00"),
    UnderTimeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(UnderTime,{{"UnderTime", type duration}}),
    OverTimeDecimal = Table.AddColumn( UnderTimeType, "OverTime Hours Number", each Duration.Hours([OverTime]-[UnderTime])+Duration.Minutes([OverTime]-[UnderTime])/60),
    WorkTimeDecimal = Table.AddColumn( OverTimeDecimal, "WorkTime Hours Number", each Duration.Hours([Work Time])+Duration.Minutes([Work Time])/60)
in
    WorkTimeDecimal
```

[Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNgZW.png)

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGU2o.png)

Comment: Great share with detailed steps! You can consider accepting your post as Answer after waiting for 48 hours. https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/

Comment: Interesting read. I'm beginning to wonder if you can bypass excel and just use Power BI to call the data directly from Outlook. Possibly after that download to excel without the VBA?

Comment: Yes. I did't know it is possible but it is . I add other answer with This solution

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to gns100 I did small investigation and found out that VBA is not needed. Power Query can access Exchange server and download this data directly.
In below code you need to change e-mail and calendar name to your own Calendar name has to be taken from properties of calendar , not text visible in GUI.
I will share ready Excel later on but M script without parameters looks simple :

```
let
    Source = Exchange.Contents("username@domainname"),
    GetCalendars = Source{[Name="Calendar"]}[Data],
    SelectCalendar = Table.SelectRows(GetCalendars, each ([Folder Path] = "\Calendar\Work Timesheet\")),
    SelectColumns = Table.SelectColumns(SelectCalendar,{"Subject", "Start", "End"}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(SelectColumns, each Date.IsInCurrentMonth([Start])),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Start", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Custom_0" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Start Date", each Date.From([Start])),
     #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom_0" , "Start Time", each Time.From([Start])),
     #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2" , "End Time", each Time.From([End])),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom3",{{"Start Time", type time}, {"End Time", type time}, {"Start Date", type date}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Start", "End"}),
    mSort = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"Start Date", Order.Ascending}, {"Start Time", Order.Ascending}}),
    WorkTime = Table.AddColumn(mSort, "WorkTime", each if [Subject] = "WORK" or [Subject]="WORK OVER" then [End Time]-[Start Time] else "00:00:00"),
    WorkTimeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(WorkTime,{{"WorkTime", type duration}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(WorkTimeType, {"Start Date"}, {{"Subject", each List.Min([Subject]), type text}, {"Start Time", each List.Min([Start Time]), type nullable time}, {"End Time", each List.Max([End Time]), type nullable time}, {"Work Time", each List.Sum([WorkTime]), type nullable duration}}),
    StandardTime = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Standard time", each if [Subject]="WORK" or [Subject]="FREE" then "08:00:00" else "00:00:00"),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(StandardTime, "Work Day", each if[Standard time]>"00:00:00" then 1 else null),
    StandardTimeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom1",{{"Standard time", type duration}}),
    OverTime = Table.AddColumn(StandardTimeType, "OverTime", each if[Work Time]-[Standard time]>=Duration.From("00:00:00")  then [Work Time]-[Standard time] else "00:00:00"),
    OverTimeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(OverTime,{{"OverTime", type duration}}),
    UnderTime = Table.AddColumn(OverTimeType, "UnderTime", each if[Work Time]-[Standard time]<Duration.From("00:00:00")  then -[Work Time]+[Standard time] else "00:00:00"),
    UnderTimeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(UnderTime,{{"UnderTime", type duration}}),
    OverTimeDecimal = Table.AddColumn( UnderTimeType, "OT Hrs Cnt", each Duration.Hours([OverTime]-[UnderTime])+Duration.Minutes([OverTime]-[UnderTime])/60),
    WorkTimeDecimal = Table.AddColumn( OverTimeDecimal, "WT Hrs Cnt", each Duration.Hours([Work Time])+Duration.Minutes([Work Time])/60)
in
    WorkTimeDecimal
```

Comment: Yes, I've been using this method (PQ without VBA) quite a lot and it seems quite reliable.